# Update table row without sql query, REST API

Tags: java, rest, crud

I want to know how to update row data in rest service. The row was created with EntityManager, that is em.merge, no insert statement used. 
Now I want to update some fields in the created row, please how do I go about this?

**bookDto.java**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "author")
private String author;
```

**service.java**

```
public class BookService {
private EntityManager em;
//create new, works fine, creates without sql insert query
public BookDto createBook(BookDto bookDto) {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setName(bookDto.getName());
        book.setAuthor(bookDto.getAuthor());
    return new BookDto(em.merge(book));
}
// update existing
public BookDto updateBook(BookDto bookDto){
  // I need help to complete this update method
  // The row gets updated based on @id 
  // on the name
}
}
```

How do I complete the update method, thanks.

Comment: Show the whole code of bookDto.java.

Comment: @mentallurg just the same setter and getter part missing, otherwise the same code..

Comment: If you don't show code nobody will point you to a problem in your code.

Answer (score 1):

if the object of BookDto you are passing the updateBook method contains the @id in this case name you will just use em.merge

```
public BookDto updateBook(BookDto bookDto){
  return em.merge(bookDto);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the error: Object: book.test.services.dto.BookDto@2392a975 is not a known Entity type.